# How to create Html table tr inside td

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create table in html. I have following design to create. I had added tr inside the td but somehow the table is not created as per the design.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhhCV.png)

Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve this.

I am unable to create rounded area in the image

AidanS i tired as u suggested but i am getting like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5crL.png)

here is my html code

```
<table>
  <tr>

  <th></th>
    <th>Action Plan</th>
    <th>Condition</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>


  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>01.</td>
    <td>Advance payment</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>02.</td>
    <td>Bidding </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>03.</td>
    <td>Sending price & details of the vehicle  </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
 <td>04.</td>
    <td>Receiving customer confirmation  </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

     <tr>
 <td>05.</td>
    <td>Sending invoice & detail sheet for LC  </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 <td>06.</td>
    <td>Opening LC with the bank by customer   </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
 <td>07.</td>
    <td>Receiving the copy of LC  </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

   <tr>
 <td>08.</td>
    <td>Sending the shipping details   </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
 <td>09.</td>
    <td>Sending current details & refunding the Advance payment   </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 <td>10.</td>
    <td>Receiving the balance money from customer   </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
 <td>11.</td>
    <td>Sending “Gramaniladari documents "   </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>12.</td>
    <td>Clearing vehicle documents from the bank by customer.  </td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 <td>13.</td>


      <td><table><tr>
                    <td>name1</td>
                    <td>price1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>name1</td>
                    <td>price1</td>
                </tr>


</table> </td>

    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>


</table>
```

Comment: image is not clear

Comment: i think adding your codes here would be more useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This**

```html
   <table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td width="12%">1</td>
<td width="38%">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I also wonder why people down vote, without giving any constructive comments. This is a good solution for the question already.

Comment: @Sumit patel I upvoted your answer. I don't see anything wrong in it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><table><tr><td>Text here</td></tr></table></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Haha. You can't do that mate.

Comment: @HermLuna why not?

Comment: At least this can be done and is totally valid.  and you can always check at check.validator.w3.org/check.@HermLuna